# Why did my question on Google Play Games get closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I [asked a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/95326/12202) on [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games&hl=en), which is an Android application. It got closed as off-topic.

https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says that "Using a particular app on your Android device" is on-topic.

So I am confused: why did my question on Google Play Games get closed?

Comment: I didn't cast a vote either way, but most probably: because [your question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/95326/981) is not about using the app on your Android device. It is about whether or not there exists a website frontend for the service, independent of the app (or Android).

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks, I see. I've re-posted it on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ then (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201532/19400), not sure how it is going to be received there. Maybe http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ otherwise. Any other ideas of SE where that could be on-topic by any chance?

Comment: I'm not sure. We haven't seen many questions along this vein, to be honest. It's kind of a weird area between Android-specific and maybe-not-so-much. The only roughly similar situation I can think of is Google Voice, and in the past we've generally directed people to Webapps for questions about interacting with the GV service outside the app (as in, via a browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, like [eldarerathis suggested](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/why-did-my-question-on-google-play-games-get-closed#comment4189_1858), the question was independent of the Android OS or using an app thereon. Hence this was closed *on the grounds of being off-topic*.

And on the other hand, *Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher* are explicitly off-topic and *does not* apply to your question.